# What is adf.ly and how does it somehow usurp my clicks?

Tags: google-chrome, browser-addons, advertisements

Originally I thought it was the website doing it. But I was using my Encrypted bank account and I got redirected to an adf.ly advertisement. I'm guessing its a Chrome extension that might be causing it or its Chrome itself. Does anyone know the best way to prevent this? I installed a couple extensions but I would rather uninstall whatever extension might be causing this, or stop using Chrome all together.

Comment: Definitely follow @jmc302005's advice, but also stop using Chrome for banking (and other vital transactions) until this is resolved.  While it may not happen, it is possible that the offending extension/add-on is capable of stealing vital information (yes, all extensions are, but seeing how this one changes banking links makes me that much more suspicious).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

adfly is a re-directer used by people to get clicks for money with advertising. You have to wait a few seconds then in the top right corner you can click skip ad. They also claim the purpose of it is to shorten the length of links. Either way it is a advertising ploy. Read [here](http://adf.ly/) for further information.

As for the Chrome thing I don't use it. But a quick search found [this](http://code.google.com/p/adfly/). So you seem to have an extension installed on chrome that turns your links into "adfly" links. I would remove all your Chrome extensions then install them back one at a time using Chrome in between each install to find the culprit.

Comment: Thanks jmc! I super appreciate it. What a sleezy way to get ad clicks! ha!

Comment: No problem. Very happy to help. And yes that is very sleazy. All advertising is unfortunately.